# How to mark multiple files in netrw?

Tags: netrw

I tried using `MF *.h` for example to select all the files in the current directory that end with `.h` but this doesnt work.

What are good ways to mark multiple files using netrw?

Comment: You can do it with vim-netranger by pressing `v`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it's a bug, but I did email the author.

## Solution 1 (set working directory)

If you have set (the default was `1`)
`let g:netrw_keepdir = 0`

Which changes your working directory as your browse, it surprisingly works.

Another option is to do `cd` or `lcd` on the `netrw` buffer window to change the working directory to the current file's path. And do an `:MF *.h`

Note: Not to be confused as ex command (starts with `:`) `cd` is actually a normal binding on netrw buffer. It used to be `c` on previous version of `netrw`.

#### Example workflow. `:lcd %` (on the netrw buffer)

1. `lcd` is for the local window, and `%` expands to the current path of the buffer
2. `:MF *.h`

## Solution 2 (apply `mf` on visual selection)

Visually select the files you want, then `:normal mf`, it'll show as `:'<,'>normal mf` to indicate selection